# Making a NewGame button using WPF and MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm "playing" with WPF and MVVM (purpose: to perhaps demo with students as alternative to WinForms) with C# and for such purposes built a trivial game of High-Low (guess the number etc ..)  I'm relatvely new to C# and having followed various online tutorials have a working "game" except for a command to start a new game from within the interface.  My kludge solution has been to put the following into the code behind which is basically the same as calling MainWindow() again:

```
private void Restart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Game = new HighLowGameViewModel();
            this.DataContext = Game;
        }
```

But I'd like to get the same effect by using an ICommand in the ViewModel.

The Constructor for the VM is:

```
public HighLowGameViewModel()
        {
            _game = new HighLowGameModel(1, 10);
            MakeGuessCommand = new HighLowViewGameGuessCommand(this);
            NewGameCommand = new HighLowViewGameNewGameCommand(this);
            
        }
```

The MakeGuessCommand implements ICommand and works fine, it sits in its own class as I'm avoiding using things like RelayCommand for now.  I created a new class for NewGameCommand based on that:

```
private HighLowGameViewModel _viewModel;

        public HighLowViewGameNewGameCommand(HighLowGameViewModel viewModel)
        {
            _viewModel = viewModel;
        }

        #region ICommand Members
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }


        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return _viewModel.CanMakeNewGame;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _viewModel.NewGame();
        }
```

And _viewModel.NewGame():

```
public void NewGame()
        {
            int currentMax = _game.Max;
            Debug.Write("I am trying to make  new game");
            _game = new HighLowGameModel(1, currentMax);
        }
```

It runs this code when clicking on the button in the view which has its Command set to MakeNewCOmmand (Debug.Write outputs to the output window and it steps through the constructor for the HighLowGameModel etc as when the program loads) BUT none of the properties for the game are updated on the View.

I'm probably missing something silly in my ignorance of the design pattern but hope I've included enough detail for others to perhaps show me where I'm going wrong ..?  How do I refresh the application and return it to a starting state?

---

Following comment from Clemens (thank you): adding that `_game` is declared as a property in the `HighLowViewModel` class, it holds the data for the game (e.g. user's guess, random value chosen by the computer, number of lives left etc).  Each of these is bound to the View through that object in the ViewModel.  Seems to work fine, values get updated and displayed as they are bound to the controls on the window.  But when calling the command to create a new game, which in turn calls the constructor for the Model setting new values (starting values) for the game:

```
public HighLowGameModel Game
        {
            get { return _game; }
            set { 
                _game = value;
            }
        }

        #region Constructor
        public HighLowGameViewModel()
        {
            _game = new HighLowGameModel(1, 10);
            MakeGuessCommand = new HighLowViewGameGuessCommand(this);
            NewGameCommand = new HighLowViewGameNewGameCommand(this);
            
        }
        #endregion
```

However, the elements in the view are not updated with the new values for the start of the game.

Comment: It is unclear what exactly the `_game` member in HighLowGameViewModel is, and how the view is linked to it. It should however be a public property with change notification to update the UI. Change notification means that the owning class implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and the setter of the property fires the PropertyChanged event of that interface.

Comment: For reference see [Data binding overview in WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0) and [Binding Sources Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-sources-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Answer (score 0):

---

SOLUTION:

ViewModel class needed to implement INotifyPropertyChanged as well as the Model (... I reckon I've got further thinking to do on this i.e. whether it should *only* be the ViewModel implementing that interface but that seems to lead to duplication ...?).  Anyway, on calling the NewGame() in that class, it also needed to indicated OnPropertyChanged("Game") as pointed out in the comment below (Thanks again).